# Strange behaviour of UNIX find command

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, find

OK this might be silly, but it's really annoying.

I've been experiencing trouble with `find` lately and I can't figure out what the problem is. Basically I'm trying to `find` a folder called `bin` that I know must be inside another folder called `lib`. For this, I use the following command.

```
find * -type d -wholename "lib/bin"
```

This effectively finds the folder I'm looking for, **but only if I am in the directory containing `lib`**. If I move one directory up, i.e.

```
cd..
```

the same command above will **return nothing**.

I know that `find` automatically searches recursively, so I don't understand why it can't find my directory in the second case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-wholepath`, as name implies, matches the whole name of the element. See `man find` for the description of the `-path` option (which has made the `-wholepath` obsolete).

What you want is something like this:

```
find ./* -type d -path "*/lib/bin"
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a quick fix. and the `man` pages were not very clear on this.